# How can I randomize existing byte array?

Tags: python, random

I create an array of bytes.

```py
array = bytearray(random.randint(1, 8192))

# Now, how can I randomize array's elements?
```

Now how can I randomize each elements of the `array`?

Just like,

```java
// with Java
var array = new byte[ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 8192)];
ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextBytes(array);
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you want a bytearray with 8192 pseudo-random bytes?

Comment: @Codist Yes and/or no. I want to create an array of random length, and reuse the array *repeatedly* while randomizing those elements in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def randomize(array):
    array[:] = random.randbytes(len(array))
```

Behaves like your answer's but is ~100 times faster. Time with an average-length array (4096 bytes):

```
  23.0 ±  0.3 μs  randomize_Kelly
2191.5 ± 11.6 μs  randomize_Jin

Python: 3.11.4 (main, Sep  9 2023, 15:09:21) [GCC 13.2.1 20230801]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XVJLTsMwEJVY-hSzS4JClKK2gki9AGzYhyhyyRgsGieynUqh6knYdAP77llxAA7AabAdh368iTPz_ObNm3n_bHv90ojd7qPT7Orm92LPZFOD5jVyDbxuG6n9H3EZpanmSvMnNWZrpCI28QrXxIdUr8arpKJqakIqZP7O37C84yKkUtI-ygiYwxoJHLiwkGcMVzimfd4eF8h5AQtPlNgPFzpMY7iezaLzIve4WvUnZQaK7Ixi2WtUxzUJYZ0wDS5OFcfn3IS4BwZnKdw9nKa3c0NgLbMEG5ZBXrj-mO3PEW-dUOukCpmXpi0613AJE5w7vLZ4ZTzEKnR0OSuiPJsVhXsgUXfSEAYbO4BQqyibJxO2he89bNw0XGzqYj9fCgJiWcuDy5M0PbL_IO9guTaahuGHK1ovK5oB8ybFILp6iXIxiQ5wrzKhbYvCqI7IP7NvxBWI4RX7hevfC2ilnePoSAwsKUtBayxL4-WQDB7Fg9vVLIjtgiVrlIo3Iho21y_wuMh_)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `randbytes()` is what you are looking for:

```
array = bytearray( random.randbytes( random.randint(1, 8192) ) )
```

Comment: `randbytes()` might be part of the solution but your code doesn't mutate an existing bytearray object. It also doesn't produce a bytearray object at all, although it would be easy enough to convert it.

Comment: Thanks @JohnColeman for your feedback. You are right for the type of `array`, I amended my answer. As to mutating an existing array, this is not how I understood the question and I will delete my answer if this is what the OP is looking for.

Comment: Perhaps this is an XY problem and your answer can help them. I don't think that Python has anything just like the Java `nextBytes` method. If OP really wants to mutate an existing bytearray object they will probably have to loop over it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @XMehdi01 is actually what I'm asking for.

I defined the following function and it seems work.

```py
def randomize(array):
    for i in range(len(array)):
        array[i] = random.randint(0, 255)
```

Comment: This is going to be *much, much* slower than just generating a new bytearray. Also, it sounds like you're generating a single random array size up front and then keeping the bytearray permanently at that size as you regenerate the contents. Depending on your use case, that could be an issue.